# Does there exist a way by which i can use WMI classes in java

Tags: codeigniter, java, javascript, python, perl

Hi i want to use WMI classes to find out the application and products information. But the problem is that i want to use java or any scripting language like python, javascript or perl. I have heard about JWMI, it may be an option. Can anyone help me regarding this???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript and Java aren't the same thing.

#### JavaScript

JavaScript is available under Windows Scripting Host (WSH). With it, it is fairly easy to access WMI:

```
var loc = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
var svc = loc.ConnectServer(".", "root\\cimv2");
coll = svc.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process");
var items = new Enumerator(coll);

while ( !items.atEnd() )
{
    WScript.Echo(items.item().Name);
    items.moveNext();
}
```

#### jWMI (Java)

jWMI is a small library to enable Java to make general WMI queries. It seems to be [available here](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/)

http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/

It also seems easy to use (though I am not sure how powerful or complete it is):

```
String name = getWMIValue("Select Name from Win32_ComputerSystem", "Name");
```

#### WBEM (Java)

WMI is a Microsoft implementation of [*Web Based Enterprise Management*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-Based_Enterprise_Management) (WBEM). There is also a [Java implementation of general WBEM](http://wbemservices.sourceforge.net/) which will be at some level compatible with WMI.

This might be the most complete true Java implementation you're going to find. If your needs are above tiny scripting (such as implementing a WBEM/WMI provider), then you might want to look into this option.

Answer (score 2):

For the scripting language: Download [Scriptomatic 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178) and let the wizard create WMI code for VBScript, JScript, Perl, and Python. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=d87daf50-e487-4b0b-995c-f36a2855016e&displaylang=en) is something similar for Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used WMI through [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)

Answer (score 1):

[JInterop](http://www.j-interop.org/introduction.html) is a good option for WMI operations in java.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [J-Interop](http://www.j-interop.org/index.html) too. Here's a nice example:  http://www.vijaykandy.com/2009/09/windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-from-java/

Answer (score 1):

JWMI performing WMI operations by creating and executing vb scripts with the relevant queries.
I am using [J-Interop](http://www.j-interop.org/) which is an open source and a good option.
There are also [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/), [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/) and [EZ Jcom](http://www.ezjcom.com/).

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform WMI queries I recommend you my library [WMI4Java](https://github.com/profesorfalken/WMI4Java).

It is very easy to use:

```
Map<String, String> wmiObjectProperties =   
    WMI4Java.get().getWMIObject("Win32_BIOS");
```

Comment: how to get the disk manufacturing serial? device id and another thing related to disk?