# Is there any API to manage VisualSVN server using JAVA

Tags: java, svn, visualsvn-server, svnkit, javahl

Is there any API to manage VisualSVN server using JAVA. I want to write a java code which will manage VisualSVN server, Changes rights and permission etc in Java. Or any other approach to this with less complication. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended libraries/howtos for using WMI with java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610063/recommended-libraries-howtos-for-using-wmi-with-java)

Comment: wut? You are wrong. VisualSVN Server's WMI provider is used for server administration tasks, such as permission and repository management etc. You have to access the WMI provider to be able to perform those tasks and the referred thread describes how you can do this with Java.

Comment: To all those trying this with java.. no Pure Java API. You might have to use JACOB or other such API.

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote it then. :)

Comment: BTW, did you see the VisualSVN Server PowerShell cmdlets for server administration? See https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage VisualSVN Server via WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation), see some examples here [Control VisualSVN Server from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017282/control-visualsvn-server-from-c-sharp/10030008#10030008) and here [SVN Rights Management Tool using Windows Authentication method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684522/svn-rights-management-tool-using-windows-authentication-method/14686167#14686167). You can acess WMI via Java but the question is why you want to use Java for such task.

For examples of using Java to access WMI see these threads:

- [Does there exist a way by which i can use WMI classes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288580/does-there-exist-a-way-by-which-i-can-use-wmi-classes-in-java)
- [Recommended libraries/howtos for using WMI with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610063/recommended-libraries-howtos-for-using-wmi-with-java)