# get Commandline defined output?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, wmic

When I use

```
wmic process where name="Process Name.exe" get Commandline
```

I get back

```
"C:/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Process Name.exe" "8394" "NameLauncher.exe" "C:/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/NameClient.exe" "162.139.44.201 5121 Em1ZuUZYVGu4qfe9annYgQ== 42835997"
```

What is **== 42835997**? The number stays the same as compared to **Em1ZuUZYVGu4qfe9annYgQ**.

Also. What do I need to write to output only the **162.139.44.201 5121** part replacing the space with a line break? Is it maybe also possible to output it in notepad? Also with the line break? This would be awesome!

Comment: Command lines are defined by the application. You need to ask the author of Process Name.exe what their command line means.

Comment: Does someone know what to write do get back the ip adress only?

Comment: If you want a way to extract the IP address from the command line, the answer is "write a program or script".

Comment: Hm Im not able to. I only have experience in dealing with web languages.

Comment: Then why did you tag the question C++? [WMI can be accessed from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6288599/902497).