# detect if windows is running on hyper-v virtual machine

Tags: java, virtual, hyper-v

Is there a way to detect if a windows operating system is running on Hyper-V? I am going to implement it in Java (I found out that there is a way for C++ but not for java) so that my application will be able to recognize if it is running on native or virtual(explicitly Hyper-V) system.

Comment: Out of interest, what do you intend to use that information for?  This sounds to me like it might be a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); does your program really need to know this specific piece of information?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem should be in executing a WMI query from java.
Libraries like [jWMI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/) could help you.

Also you could try to find an answer on the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288580/does-there-exist-a-way-by-which-i-can-use-wmi-classes-in-java).

After that you could use your code written in C++ to easily execute your windows discovery.

Hope it helps.